# How to remove/disabled ripple of button when focus via pressing TAB KEY

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have used material-ui in my project. When I use TAB KEY for moving around the form, one component to another, there is an animation effect that I want to remove.

Please check the attached Image for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9kdd.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Buttop props disableFocusRipple
 disableFocusRipple={true}

or disableRipple